# float:left stops click event on android?

Tags: android, css, onclick, css-float

i have two divs side by side (via float:left).
on this two divs i got a lot of other divs waiting to be clicked.
on firefox it works, but in android, when i click the click event is just triggered sometimes.
if i remove the floats:left everything works.

any ideas?

my divs:

```
<div style="float:left; width: 50%">
    <div class="btn" id="andBtn">and</div>
    <div class="btn" id="butBtn">but</div>
    <div class="btn" id="comeOnBtn">come on</div>
    <div class="btn" id="doNotBtn">do not</div>
    <div class="btn" id="heyBtn">hey</div>
    <div class="btn" id="howBtn">how</div>
    <div class="btn" id="iDontBtn">i don`t</div>
    <div class="btn" id="iAmBtn">i am</div>
    <div class="btn" id="itIsBtn">it is</div>
</div>  

<div style="float:left; width: 50%">
    <div class="btn" id="noBtn">no</div>
    <div class="btn" id="thatIsBtn">that is</div>
    <div class="btn" id="thereIsBtn">there is</div>
    <div class="btn" id="thisIsBtn">this is</div>
    <div class="btn" id="waitBtn">wait</div>
    <div class="btn" id="whatBtn">what</div>
    <div class="btn" id="whyBtn">why</div>
    <div class="btn" id="yeahBtn">yeah</div>
    <div class="btn" id="youBtn">you</div>
</div>
```

binding the click event:

```
for(var category in categories){

    var e = function(category){
    $('#'+category+'Btn').click(function(){
        alert('click')
        show(category)
    })}
    e(category)
```

Comment: if i position the divs with position:absolute it works...

Comment: Do you float both DIVs on the left?
If you want them side by side you can do this:
`<div style="float: left; width: 50%;"></div>
<div style="float: right; width: 50%;"></div>`

Comment: Does it work on Android as expected if you set pixel widths rather than percentages?

Comment: try adding overflow:hidden next to float:left

Comment: I think divs might be overlapping, maybe android is throwing a default margin/padding onto the divs? Have you tried them at lets say, 48%?

Comment: i used a completely other layout as workaround... but thx for the help!

Comment: @normoral could you post it as an answer and mark it as answered to help others please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `position: absolute` works

```
<div style="position:absolute; width: 50%">

    <div class="btn" id="costumBtn" style="background-color: darkorange;">favorites</div>

    <div class="btn" style="background-color: darkblue;" id="laughBtn">laugh</div>

    <div class="btn" style="background-color: darkblue;" id="helloBtn">hello</div>


    <div class="btn" id="alrightBtn">alright _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="andBtn">and _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="butBtn">but _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="comeOnBtn">come on _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="doNotBtn">do not _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="heyBtn">hey _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="howBtn">how _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="iDontBtn">i don`t _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="iAmBtn">i am _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="itIsBtn">it is _</div>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute; left:50%; width: 50%">       
    <div class="btn" id="randomBtn" style="background-color: darkgreen;">random</div>

    <div class="btn" style="background-color: darkblue;" id="soundBtn">sound</div>

    <div class="btn" style="background-color: darkblue;" id="bestBtn">best</div>

    <div class="btn" id="noBtn">no _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="thatIsBtn">that is _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="thereIsBtn">there is _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="thisIsBtn">this is _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="waitBtn">wait _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="whatBtn">what _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="whyBtn">why _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="yeahBtn">yeah _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="youBtn">you _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="allBtn" style="background-color: black;">all 1153</div>
</div>
```